# UICollectionView and Deselecting cell doesnt work. once it has been selected. what is the error here?

Tags: swift, swift2, uicollectionview

Hey i have some code that executes fine but i cant deselect a cell from the UICollectionView. it stays selected once it has been selected. tried most of the methods in other posts but couldn't solve it. please do take a look and let me know

MY VIEWCONTROLLER.SWIFT part

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabela: UILabel!

var selectedPerson: Person?
var hasSelectedImage: Bool = false
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()



let missingPeople = [
    Person(personImageUrl: "person1.jpg"),
    Person(personImageUrl: "person2.jpg"),
    Person(personImageUrl: "person3.jpg"),
    Person(personImageUrl: "person4.jpg"),
    Person(personImageUrl: "person5.jpg"),
    Person(personImageUrl: "person6.png")
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("loadPicker:"))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    selectedImg.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
}





func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return missingPeople.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 // so kur da napisam ovde

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PersonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PersonCell

    //cell.selected = true
    //collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)

    let person = missingPeople[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(person)
    return cell
}





func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.selectedPerson = missingPeople[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! PersonCell
    cell.configureCell(selectedPerson!)
    cell.setSelected()

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImg.image = pickedImage
        hasSelectedImage = true
    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func showErrorAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Person & Image", message: "Please select a missing person to check and an image", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(ok)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func loadPicker(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary // .Camera

    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
} ..... ..... ...... and so on
```

PersonCell.swift

```
import UIKit
class PersonCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var personImage: UIImageView!
var person: Person!



func configureCell(person: Person) {
    self.person = person
    self.addOrRemoveBorder()
    if let url = NSURL(string: "\(baseURL)\(person.personImageUrl!)") {
        downloadImage(url)


    }
}

func downloadImage(url: NSURL) {
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            self.personImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.person.personImage = self.personImage.image

        }
    }

}

func getDataFromUrl(url: NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) ->Void)){

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
    }.resume()

}

func addOrRemoveBorder() {
    if self.person.isSelected == true {
        personImage.clipsToBounds = false
        personImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        personImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor

    } else {
        personImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        personImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0

    }
}

func setSelected() {
    self.person.isSelected = true
    self.addOrRemoveBorder()
    self.person.downloadFaceId()
   super.selected=true

    }
}
```

What exactly seems to be the error? that i cannot deselect the cell? cause Im setting a different color on selected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a function which deselects the cell as you have with `setSelected`

```
func deselectCell() {
    self.person.isSelected = false
    self.addOrRemoveBorder()
    //self.person.downloadFaceId() //remove face id or something here
   super.selected = false
    }
}
```

**option 2 (a bit more dynamic)**

```
  func selectedOrDeselectCell(isSelected: Bool) {
    self.person.isSelected = isSelected
    self.addOrRemoveBorder()
    if isSelected{
      self.person.downloadFaceId()
    }else{
      //self.person.downloadFaceId() //remove face id or something here
    }
    super.selected = isSelected
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man ^_^ ,,,, this really helped, i created a 

 didDeselectItemAtIndexPath         in my view controller and called your method. It worked! like clockwork! thank you...